# Is it possible to add an existing tablespace datafile to a new tablespace?

Tags: oracle

Background: hard-drive died in existing Oracle12cR2 server but I was able to recover all the previous tablespaces from backup, including SYSTEM01.DBF and USERS01.DBF.  I created a new Oracle 12cR2 database server, and would like to know if I can recover any of the data in the tablespaces?

Thanks.

Comment: In a word ... "No".

Answer (score 0):

if you have oracle running in archive log mode and have a recent backup complete with all archives until the crash: yes you can. After that you can use various methods to move the data to the new database.

My question that remains is: why move it to an other database when you were able to recover the original one? The recovered database is as good as (or even better) than the new one.